# What is the asymptotic complexity of log_2(n)-log_3(n)?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, computer-science-theory

I'm trying to determine whether it is: O(1).
How can I prove it? 
In complexity terms, log_b(n) is log(n). So is O(log_2(n)-log_3(n))=O(0)=O(1)? that doesn't seem like a strong proof.
Also, this doesn't converge asymptotically, so how can it be O(1)?

Comment: It's not a strong proof, because that's not how big-O works.  Otherwise you could say `O(x^2) == O(3.x^2) - O(2.x^2) == O(1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...your proof is wrong. O(log_2(n)-log_3(n))==O(log(n)/log(2)-log(n)/log(3))==O(log(n)*(1/log(2)-1/log(3))=O(Clog(n))=O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might have a look at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)

It gives some nice plots for [log_2(n)-log_3(n)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_2%28n%29-log_3%28n%29)

And, even more important for you, it describes [O(log_2(n)-log_3(n))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=O%28log_2%28n%29-log_3%28n%29%29)

Comment: If you have a look at the plot, you could see it immediately